# Adding a new row in a table after every 3 images from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-table, gallery

I have a gallery where images are uploaded via MySQL database and displayed on my site in a table. Problem is, the images are inserted into rows of one. I need someone to **alter my script** to where a new row will be added after every 3 columns (images).

I asked this before but deleted the thread so I could start over. I've done a lot of research and learned a few things, but I cannot figure out how to write the script to fit my needs.

Script:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY id ASC";
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row["img"]; ?></a><br>Size: <?php echo $row["size"]; ?><br>Views: <?php echo $row["clicks"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="3">No results found.</td>
<?php   
}
?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open and close your  tags not every iteration, but every 3 iterations. The resulting code might look something like this:

```
  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">

    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." ORDER BY id ASC";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
        $i=0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
            if ($i++ % 3 == 0) echo "<tr>";
    ?>    
            <td><a href="<?php echo $row["link"]; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row["img"]; ?></a><br>Size: <?php echo $row["size"]; ?><br>Views: <?php echo $row["clicks"]; ?></td>
    <?php
            if ($i % 3 == 0) echo "</tr>";
    ?>
    <?php
        }
        if ($i % 3 != 0) echo "</tr>";
    } else {
    ?>
    <tr><td colspan="3">No results found.</td>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works and looks great. You saved me a headache. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

You the guy with this answer if ($i % 3 == 0) echo ""; are the savior. I tried so much in JavaScript. but haven't forgotten I could do this on back end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) questions and answers that you found helpful.