# How to echo mysql results into 3 table columns instead of just 1

Tags: php, html, mysql

EDIT: TO STACKOVERFLOW The suggested post does NOT answer my question. I already saw that one. Why would you close my question so early? I already said in this post that they didn't answer my question nor did they help!

first, I attempted to use several dozen similar posts that were auto suggested here, as well as hours of searching on google. I should tell you that I am not very experienced so the examples I did see, I couldn't figure out how to make it work for my page.

This is what I'm attempting to do. I want to take these results and split them into 3 table columns, where each cell has all the info for each entry. The columns need to be fixed at 3, and the rows are unlimited as more images are added.

NOTE: Please tell me how to fix this or what is wrong before closing it or -1 me. I already searched all the similar posts so I wont know how to fix this unless someone tells me. Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: This is all within a table already, which is good. But I need to split the results within the table into a new table with 3 columns

EDIT 2: I am needing everything showing here in one cell, and then it loop to repeat for 2 more cells, then a new row with 3 more, like so:

[image]

This is so each row in the database has it's own cell

And then a new row with 3 more entries from the database, and so on

Here is my current code:

```
    <div align="center"><img src="header.jpg"><br>
      <br>
      <a href="form.php" target="_blank"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#9999FF">CLICK 
      HERE TO ADD YOUR SELFIE</font></a><br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <table width="50%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tr> 
        <td> 
          <div align="center"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php
      // Include the database configuration file
      include 'config.php';
      // Get images from the database
      $query = $db->query("SELECT nameviewer, file_name FROM image ORDER BY uploaded_on DESC");
      if($query->num_rows > 0){
          while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
              $nameviewer = 'uploads/'.$row["nameviewer"];
              $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_name"];
      ?>
    
    <a href="<?= $imageURL; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?= $imageURL; ?>" width="150" /></a><br>
            <font color='lightblue'> <b><?php 
    echo htmlspecialchars($row["nameviewer"]);  ?></b></font><br>
            <font size="2"><i><font color="#999999">Click The Pic To Expand</font></i></font><br>
            _______________<br><br>
            <?php }} ?>
    </font></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: `<font>` is obsolete, you should use `<span style="...">`

Comment: Okay thanks @Barmar but that isn't what I'm asking to do for this. The font tag isn't causing me any issues so far

Comment: I know, that's why I put it in a comment while I was writing the real answer.

Comment: OMG! They closed my question again after I clearly stated that the other answers on here did not help my code issue. Man this site makes it incredibly hard to get help!

Comment: Who is they? I closed it after I figured out what you were asking about. The other question seems to be exactly on point.

Comment: If you can't get it to work, show how you tried to implement it, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: This google search finds a buch of other questions: "php new table row after 3 rows"

Comment: I agree with Barmar's reasons for closing this - the answers at that question may not have helped you, but it is fundamentally the same question. Also please note that when your question is closed, that is feedback for you - it does not make sense for people to tell you what's wrong before closing it, because the closing is what tells you what is wrong. If you feel that you are not asking the same question, please reword your post to differentiate it from the other one, otherwise it will likely remain closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the answer at [Adding a new row in a table after every 3 images from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093045/adding-a-new-row-in-a-table-after-every-3-images-from-database)

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
// Get images from the database
$query = $db->query("SELECT nameviewer, file_name FROM image ORDER BY uploaded_on DESC");
?>
<table width="50%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
    $nameviewer = 'uploads/'.$row["nameviewer"];
    $imageURL = 'uploads/'.$row["file_name"];
    if ($i++ % 3 == 0) { // start new row before each group of 3
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    ?>
    <td>
        <a href="<?= $imageURL; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?= $imageURL; ?>" width="150" /></a><br>
        <font color='lightblue'> <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["nameviewer"]);  ?></b></font><br>
        <font size="2"><i><font color="#999999">Click The Pic To Expand</font></i></font>
    </td>
    <?php
    if ($i % 3 == 0) { // end row after a group of 3
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
if ($i % 3 != 0) { // end the last row if it wasn't an even multiple of 3
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

There's no need for `if($query->num_rows > 0)`. If there are no rows, the `while` loop will just stop immediately and not output anything. You only need that if you want to display another message if there's no data to show -- you could show that in the `else` block.

Comment: thank you but this gives me an error 500. Also it puts each section in a different column. I am trying to put Picture, Name, and "click the pic to expand" all in one cell.

Comment: The question says "3 table columns".

Comment: What's the error message in the PHP error log?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use the technique at the duplicate question.

Comment: I updated my question to show what I am trying to do. You're answer doesn't give those results though. But thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer should do what you want. What is it doing instead?

Comment: Sorry, I copied something wrong. I just updated it.

Comment: yes that did the trick. And I can learn from that too. Thank you very much. Too bad they closed this but I hope others can learn from your excellent assistance. Thank you.

Comment: So, should the question be re-opened as you've also answered it?

Comment: "They" didn't close it, I did. There's nothing to learn from this one, since my answer is exactly the same as the duplicate I linked to.